# QJsonDocument to list or array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, json, list, qt

I've tried this code and works, but I didn't understand how can get json and convert in array or list with Qt.
My code:

```
QEventLoop eventLoop;


QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
QObject::connect(&mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));


QNetworkRequest req(QUrl(QString("http://myurljson.com/getjson")));

QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.get(req);
eventLoop.exec(); // blocks stack until "finished()" has been called

if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {

    QString strReply = (QString)reply->readAll();    

    qDebug() << "Response:" << strReply;

    QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());
    QJsonObject jsonObj = jsonResponse.object();

    qDebug() << "test:" << jsonObj["MCC_Dealer"].toString();
    qDebug() << "test1:" << jsonObj["MCC_User"].toString();

    delete reply;
}
else {
    //failure
    qDebug() << "Failure" <<reply->errorString();
    delete reply;
}
```

my json get (3 records from url):

> [{"MCC_Dealer":'test',"MCC_User":'test',"CurrentDealer":'test',"CurrentUser":'test'},{"MCC_Dealer":'test',"MCC_User":'test',"CurrentDealer":'test',"CurrentUser":'test'},{"MCC_Dealer":'test',"MCC_User":'test',"CurrentDealer":'test',"CurrentUser":'test'}]

I need to get json and set in list or in array.
My target is convert json response in array or list with c++ and Qt.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your JSON response is an array. Each element of the array has four JSON objects with string values: "MCC_Dealer", "MCC_User", "CurrentDealer", "CurrentUser". Please clarify, how do you want to store them in the list.

Comment: Each line is an object, I want to put it in an object list, such as List <myobject> obj = new List <myobject> (); And obj.add (line1); Etc etc .. i come from c # but i would like to do this in c ++

Comment: Well, but you already have a `QJsonArray` which stores each of the mentioned objects. Why do you need another structure (list) to store them? If you write `QJsonArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.array();` you will get what you need, I think.

Comment: Work! to call a properties, from first element, i do jsonArray[0]['MCC_Dealer'] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my comments, your JSON response is already an array, so you don't need to create additional structures to store the data you got. In order to de-serialize your data you can do the following:

```
[..]
QJsonArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.array();

for (auto it = jsonArray.constBegin(); it != jsonArray.constEnd(); ++it)
{
    const QJsonValue &val = *it;

    // We expect that array contains objects like:
    // {"MCC_Dealer":'test',"MCC_User":'test',"CurrentDealer":'test',"CurrentUser":'test'}
    QJsonObject o = val.toObject();

    // Iterate over all sub-objects. They all have string values.
    for (auto oIt = o.constBegin(); oIt != o.constEnd(); ++oIt)
    {
        // "MCC_Dealer":'test'
        qDebug() << "Key:" << oIt.key() << ", Value:" << oIt.value().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Right answer.! Is possibile call directly one propertie ? example if i call jsonArray[0].key("MCC_Dealer")? or similar.?

Comment: I think yes, but in different way: `jsonArray[0].toObject().find("MCC_Dealer").key()` or so. But I don't recommend to do so, because in this way you don't check the correctness of values returned by each function call and it might fail in some cases.

Comment: The solution to call properties is: convert in object, QJsonObject temp = jsonarray[n].toObject(); and after you call temp.value("yourvalue").toString(); - this works. Thanks